# Как ввести последовательность чисел, записанных в строку, в массив

Tags: python, python-3.x, ввод

Дана строка: `1 3 9 3 2`. На C++ это выглядело бы так:

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    std::cin >> b[i];
```

А как сделать это на Python?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 10):

Можно воспользоваться генератором списков:

```
In [2]: xs = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
1 3 9 3 2

In [3]: xs
Out[3]: [1, 3, 9, 3, 2]
```

Можно воспользоваться функцией `map` (Python 3.x):

```
In [4]: xs = list(map(int, input().split()))
1 3 9 3 2

In [5]: xs
Out[5]: [1, 3, 9, 3, 2]
```

В случае Python 2.x вызов `list` не нужен:

```
In [6]: xs = map(int, raw_input().split())
1 3 9 3 2

In [7]: xs
Out[7]: [1, 3, 9, 3, 2]
```

Comment: Чтобы первый пример поддерживал и Питон 2 и 3 одновременно, можно `sys.stdin.readline()` или `fileinput.input()` вместо `input()` использовать, если массив вероятно другой программой или из нескольких файлов может задаваться (автоматизированный многострочный ввод, без поддержки ручного редактирования).